# How can I establish what is causing the disposal of the `HttpListenerRequest` inside an `IOwinContext.Request`

Tags: c#, owin, idisposable, httplistenerrequest

I have a C# API using OWIN.

In one of my OwinMiddleware components I read some properties off `context.Request` after the Controller processes the request, and *sometimes* this blows up with an "Object is already disposed" error from the `HttpListenerRequest` deep inside the `IOwinRequest`.

So, *something* is triggering that disposal.
I believe this is a bug, because according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33568392/should-i-dispose-the-streams-in-owins-context-when-i-use-them/33587572#33587572) that shouldn't happen.

So I need to work out what is causing that disposal ... but I can't because I have no idea when it's ocurring (other than "before this point").

Ideally, I want to do something that causes the debugger to stop at some point closely related to when the disposal happens.

Things I've tried and which haven't worked:

- I can get Rider to decompile some obvious bits of the .NET code, but Breakpoints set in there don't hit.
- I can replace the `context.Request` with a wrapped version of itself, and so I thought that I could track the Dispose call on the `OwinRequest` down through the layers ... except the Request object isn't `IDisposable`, and I can't see any other obvious way that the `OwinRequest` is in control of when the internal disposal happens.
- I can't find a seam to be able to get at where the inner object gets set up - it looks like WebApi does that for me somewhere that I can't reach.

Comment: See if this helps : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.getbaseexception?view=net-6.0#system-exception-getbaseexception  It is referenced from following page :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistenerexception?view=net-6.0

Comment: @jdweng How do you think that's going to help? I know what exception is being thrown ... its an ObjectDisposedException ... my question is **when did that object get disposed?**, not "why has the property call failed?"

Comment: It is probably being disposed due to an exception.

Comment: @jdweng ... I agree ... but `Exception.GetBaseException` won't help me if I can't *find* that exception in the first place?

Comment: If he exception is using THROW than the exception is sent to the next higher level exception handler.  It is like the stack trace.  With c# every method has default exception handler.  So as your app calls nested methods you have a chain of event handlers.  So when a low level exception occurs the exception message is passed to next higher exception handler and you then have a stack trace.

Comment: @jdweng all of that is true but entirely irrelevant. Because I'm not **in** the relevant exception handling context. The current exception doesn't ... and **CANNOT** ... know why this object was originally disposed because that event is in the unconnected past. This isn't an exception that has been derived from or is a re-handled version of some previous exception.
That original exception happened, and was fully handled, and the code continued, and now a new entirely separate exception has been thrown because of the state that the objects were put into.

Comment: I need some way to find out where and when that (presumed) first exception happened - and the current exception cannot know that, because that information is not known by the execution context, and not stored by the object which threw this exception.

Comment: The only way of been able to find source is to step through the code.